# JFET- circuit. Uds and Id dependency?

Tags: transistors, jfet, current-drain

For a lab assigment I did measurements with the oszilloscope for the circuit below containung JFET BF245A.

[image]

I obtained those curves for Id (drain) in relation to Ugs (gate-source) for the Uds (drain-source) values of 5V and 15V respectively.

It can be observed in the graph, that for greater Uds(15V) the drain current also get bigger, but I cannot find an explanation for that.

Any insights why this happens?

Comment: Looks like a good exam question. What **do** you know about the relationship between gate-source voltage, drain-source voltage, and drain current? Do you have any simple models/equations that might apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much all contained in the [data sheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/BF245A-B-C.pdf) for the device. Red-lines by me: -

[image]

If you look at the graph on the left, you can see the effect of increasing \$V_{DS} has on \$I_D$. Your graph is very similar the the one on the right and, that graph is really just a morphing of the data in the left graph to the data in the right graph.

Comment: So the reason might be that  at Vds = 5V the transistor has not yet reached the saturation region? If we had chosen Vds = 10V and Vds = 15V for example, then right curve would have looked the same for both of them?

Comment: @cb_ann try it out and see but don't be too unimpressed if your model doesn't exactly tell the same story as the data sheet.